# Proving the fractional equation: $\{2^{n-1}\sqrt{3}\}=0.b_nb_{n+1}\ldots_{(2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fractional-part

> Prove that $$\{2^{n-1}\sqrt{3}\}=0.b_nb_{n+1}\ldots_{(2)}$$ where  $\sqrt 3 = 1.b_1b_2b_3 \dots _{(2)}$.
>   (Note: $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.)

I am not sure how to prove this result because of the fractional part. Should I expand $\sqrt{3}$ and then multiply by $2^{n-1}$?

Comment: Is this supposed to be in base 2?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales That's what the $(2)$ denotes.

Comment: In base ten, when you multiply by a power of ten it moves the decimal place. The same thing happens in base 2.

Comment: If $2^{n-1} = 1$ then this equation is true.  So this is true if n-1 = 0.  so n = 1.  That's all.

Comment: @fleablood this equation is true for all n

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that those 0.b_n started at n and not 1.  Well.  this is true of all bases.

Comment: @JackFrost So far as I can tell, that's a very different question altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From
$$
\sqrt 3 = 1.b_1b_2b_3 \cdots _{\,(2)} \tag1
$$ one gets, using $b_n \in \{0,1\}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left\{2^{n-1}\sqrt 3\right\} &=\left\{2^{n-1}\left( 1+\frac{b_1}{2}+\frac{b_2}{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{b_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{b_n}{2^{n}}+\frac{b_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}+\cdots \right)\right\}
\\\\&=\left\{2^{n-1}\left( 1+\frac{b_1}{2}+\frac{b_2}{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{b_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}\right)+2^{n-1}\left(\frac{b_n}{2^{n}}+\frac{b_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}+\cdots \right)\right\}
\\\\&=\left\{\underbrace{2^{n-1}+2^{n-2}b_1+2^{n-3}b_2+\cdots+b_{n-1}}_{\text{integer part}} +\overbrace{\frac{b_n}{2}+\frac{b_{n+1}}{2^2}+\cdots}^{\text{fractional part}}\right\}
\\\\&=\frac{b_n}{2}+\frac{b_{n+1}}{2^2}+\cdots
\\\\&=0.b_nb_{n+1}\cdots_{\,(2)}
\end{align}
$$ as announced.

Comment: @user19405892 If my answer is unsatisfactory, please you might want to give me a feedback, so I might improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather pointlessly complicated expression of something basically trivial.

Let $w = A.b_1b_2b3....._d = A + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i*d^{-i}$ be any number in any base $d$.

Then $d^m*w = Ab_1b_2..b_m.b_{m+1}b_{m+2}.... = A*d^m + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i*d^{m-i}$.

So $\{w*d^m\} = 0.b_{m+1}b_{m+2}.....$ for all $w$ (including $\sqrt 3$) for all $d$ (including 2) and for all $m$ (including $n -1$).

This says absolutely nothing more than "if you multiply by Base to the $m$th power, you shift the decimals over by $m$ places" which is something so utterly basic I'd expect every junior high school student to know it.

However the way this question was written was a masterwork in intimidating obfuscation.  If our goal is to scare people away from mathematics so that we can enjoy a private elitist club, this was a very good question for that goal.